# cuda function application elementwise in cuda

Tags: cuda

After multiplying a matrix A and a vector x obtaining the result y, I want to apply a function h elementwise to y.

I want to obtain z = h(A*x), where h is applied elementwise to the vector A*x.

I know how to make the matrix/vector multiplication on the GPU (with cublas). Now I want h (which is my own function, coded in C++) to be applied to the resultant vector also in GPU, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible approaches are:

1. Write your own CUDA kernel to perform the operation
2. Use [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)  (e.g. [thrust::for_each()](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__modifying.html#ga14cba62489aee67ffa6348eb74997b57) ).

Here is a worked example of both approaches:

```
$ cat t934.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>

#define DSIZE 4

#define nTPB 256

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ T myfunc(T &d){

  return d + 5;  // define your own function here
}

struct mytfunc
{
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
 void operator()(T &d){

  d = myfunc(d);
  }
};

template <typename T>
__global__ void mykernel(T *dvec, size_t dsize){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < dsize) dvec[idx] = myfunc(dvec[idx]);
}

int main(){

  // first using kernel
  float *h_data, *d_data;
  h_data = new float[DSIZE];
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, DSIZE*sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = i;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DSIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  mykernel<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(d_data, DSIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DSIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) std::cout << h_data[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // then using thrust
  thrust::host_vector<float>   hvec(h_data, h_data+DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<float> dvec = hvec;
  thrust::for_each(dvec.begin(), dvec.end(), mytfunc());
  thrust::copy_n(dvec.begin(), DSIZE, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

$ nvcc -o t934 t934.cu
$ ./t934
5,6,7,8,
10,11,12,13,
$
```

Note that in order to provide a complete example, I'm starting with a vector definition in host memory.  If you already have the vector in device memory (perhaps as a result of computing y=Ax) then you can work directly on that, by passing that vector to the CUDA kernel, or using it directly in the thrust function, using a `thrust::device_ptr` wrapper (this method is covered in the thrust quick start guide previously linked.)

The assumption I've made here is you want to use an arbitrary function of one variable.  This should handle pretty much arbitrary functions defined in `myfunc`.  However, for some categories of functions that you may be interested in, you may be able to realize it one or more CUBLAS calls as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. Two subsequent questions : Is there a difference in efficiency between the two methods (Is one of them preferable in terms of execution speed)? And does thrust compile with g++, or does it need to be in a .cu file and compiled by nvcc. Indeed, even the simple example of the thrust introduction does not compile for me with g++ (cuda 7.0.0)

Comment: Thrust, when targetting the CUDA backend, needs to be compiled with nvcc, and you should put those thrust codes in a .cu file.  For examples like what I have shown, there won't be much difference in efficiency between the two approaches.  The algorithm will be dominated by memory access, which will be the same for both approaches.

Comment: Thanks Robert. If I may disturb you another time, say for my same problem, I want to calculate y=h(A*x) and that I have to it for many vectors x, without changing the matrix A, nor the function h. Can you confirm that once the matrix A is created, it will persist in GPU memory between different kernel calls with different x arrays?

Comment: Yes, it will persist, assuming the A matrix is in global memory.